# Unable to stop overlapping of audio of current and next track

Tags: react-native, expo

I am practicing react native and created a simple audio player
https://snack.expo.dev/@megahedron69/fascinated-scone
Whenever I click on next track the previous audio does not get unloaded for some reason and both the current audio and next track audio get overlapped

```
//loading audio functions
  const loadAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
        uri: audioBookPlaylist[audState.currentIndex].uri,
      });
      setSound(sound);
      await sound.playAsync();
      setisLoaded(true);
    } catch (e) {
      setisBuffering(true);
      setisLoaded(false);
      console.log("error is " + e);
    }
  };
  const playSound = async () => {
    try {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
      });
      loadAudio();
      setisLoaded(true);
      console.log("I have loaded");
      onPlaybackStatusUpdate();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error" + " " + e);
    }
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
      setisPlaying(status.isPlaying);
      setisBuffering(status.isBuffering);
    };
  };

//next track function
const loadNextTrack = async () => {
    try {
      if (sound) {
        await sound.unloadAsync();
        setSound(null);
        audState.currentIndex < audioBookPlaylist.length - 1
          ? (audState.currentIndex += 1)
          : (audState.currentIndex = 0);
        setAudState({
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
        });
      }
      await loadAudio();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```